# sql server 2012 dialect for hibernate 4

Tags: hibernate

There is no sql server 2012 dialect inside org.hibernate.dialect for SQL Server 2012. I wanted to use 2012 dialect since there was better pagination support in SQL Server 2012 than in 2008? How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 4):

If you pull in Hibernate 4.3.0.Final you can use org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect