# Unable to reverse engineer to generate pojo using hibernate in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, sql-server-2014

I have issue with reverse engineering from database using hibernate 5. I am able to generate the hibernate.reveng.xml file but when i run using the Hibernate Code Generation Configurations, it give me the error as stated below.

I have tried with adding "hibernate." to my xml files but same thing, i can generate the hibernate.reveng.xml but not able to run Hibernate Code Generation Configurations.

This is my xml file:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
  <property name="connection.password">Password123!</property>
  <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TestDB</property>
  <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is the error i am facing.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCMetaDataConfiguration.handleTypes(JDBCMetaDataConfiguration.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCMetaDataConfiguration.getMetadataCollector(JDBCMetaDataConfiguration.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCMetaDataConfiguration.getMetadataBuildingContext(JDBCMetaDataConfiguration.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCMetaDataConfiguration.readFromJDBC(JDBCMetaDataConfiguration.java:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.Util.invokeMethod(Util.java:43)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.AbstractConfigurationFacade.readFromJDBC(AbstractConfigurationFacade.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.ConsoleExtension$2.execute(ConsoleExtension.java:308)
    at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.ConsoleExtension.buildConfiguration(ConsoleExtension.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.ConsoleExtension.runExporters(ConsoleExtension.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.ConsoleExtension.launchExporters(ConsoleExtension.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.launch.CodeGenerationLaunchDelegate.launch(CodeGenerationLaunchDelegate.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: Hope the below link helps to solve your query!!!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233399/sql-server-2012-dialect-for-hibernate-4

Comment: Hibernate can determine the correct dialect to use automatically, but in order to do this, it needs a live connection to the database.If the database you are trying to connect to does not exists you also see this error.Make sure  DB credentials are correct.

Comment: @Mihir i removed the dialect but it does not work. And i am pretty sure that my connection is correct. As i can view if from the Hibernate View after i refresh the table

Comment: @shadow Can you please post some code how you are loading hibernate configuration file, getting DB connection and performing DB operations ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

Change `<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect</property>` to `<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect</property>`

Comment: What exception you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting the whole configuration file and redo all the step to reverse engineer my pojo as per what I have posted and is working now. But I have not idea why.